# Surface of the intersection of $n$ balls

Tags: geometry, surfaces, combinatorial-geometry, spheres, convex-geometry

Suppose there are $n$ balls (possibly, of different sizes) in $\mathbb R^3$ such that their intersection $\mathfrak C$ is non-empty and has a positive volume (i.e. is not a single point). Apparently, $\mathfrak C$ is a convex body with a piecewise smooth surface — a "quilt" of sphere fragments. Let $f(n)$ be the maximal number of fragments that can be achieved for a given $n$.

Is there a simple formula or recurrence relation for $f(n)$?

Comment: Karoly Bezdek has studied "Ball-polyhedra." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 38.2 (2007): 201-230. [arXiv abs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4329), which are intersections of congruent balls. Perhaps his papers on the topic contain useful pointers for balls of different radii.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, isn't $f(n)=n$?

Comment: @user202729 You can form a 3-sided lens with 3 balls, and cut both its corners with 4th, leaving 5 spherical faces.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting integer sequence ($f(n)$ for increasing $n$) the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) folks might be interested in/know more about. (Edit: Oops, I don't know how the sequence starts, except $1, 2, ...$, probably. The third term might or might not be $3$, or $4$.) I'm seriously tempted to write an exploratory program to find higher terms experimentally...

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-many-parts-can-the-n-spheres-divide-a-space-into

Answer (score 1):

Surface and volumes can be calculated analytically for any n value. For intersections of n=5 spheres and more, they can be calculated from the 4 by 4 intersections: see theorems 4.5 and 4.6 in my book chapter:

Spheres Unions and Intersections and some of their Applications in Molecular Modeling, In: Distance Geometry: Theory, Methods, and Applications, chap. 4, pp. 61--83. Mucherino, A.; Lavor, C.; Liberti, L.; Maculan, N. (Eds.), Springer, 2013. ISBN 978-1-4614-5127-3, DOI 10.1007/978-1-4614-5128-0_4

A free preprint is available at: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01955983